# Is there fmemopen() in ZLIB

Tags: c, file-io, zlib

My code uses ZLIB, and it seems that there are problems in using `fmemopen()` and ZLIB functions afterwards...

Is there an equivalent of `fmemopen()` in ZLIB? Or how can I create it if no equivalent exists?

Comment: How about figuring why these "problems" are there or at least telling us what they are?

Comment: Afair ZLIB tries to only use standard C. `fmemopen` is described in POSIX, but not in C standard and is not available on Windows. So no, I don't think there is an equivalent for it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry. The problem is that, when a ZLIB method is applied on the file nothing happens/ NULL is returned, since the file is opened with `fmemopen()` and not with e.g. `gzopen()`.

Comment: @ezen1993 Grepping the zlib 1.2.11 sources shows no call to ``fmemopen()``. What makes you suspect there is one? Could attach gdb to the process and set a breakpoint  on it to see where it is called.

Comment: @phg It is a usefull function for making unit tests. Therefore I thought it could be included in zlib with another name....

Comment: Nothing in the zlib API uses stdio `FILE` pointers...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Shawn I'm writing a unittest and therefore I want to create a file in the memory and not on disk. Therefore I thought `fmemopen()`would be usefull for it. But afterwards I found out that the rest of the project uses sometimes zlib functions for reading of files. Other time it uses fopen, etc. It depends on, on which operating sys the program is running on. Now I'm trying to fix it without writing a file on disk for the unittest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. Furthermore, there is no need for such a thing, since zlib provides in-memory functions for compression and decompression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no such function in ZLIB

Here is a link to (per IBM) [zlib functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieac100/zLibFunctions.htm)